# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'FEE'

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, numeric

I am getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'FEE'`
and I am unable to convert it to float by following :

```
df = pd.concat([df[col].str.split()
                       .str[0]
                       .str.replace(',','').astype(float) for col in df], axis=1)
```

My column variable is as follows :

```
array(['AUTHORIZATION', 'BALANCE ADJUSTMENT', 'CARD LOAD', 'CARD UNLOAD',
       'CHARGE BACK ADVICE', 'FEE'], dtype=object)
```

Please help

My dataframe has 9 columns and 2 columns show this ValueError.

One column has value like 'REV01', 'REV02' etc.
Other one has values as ['AUTHORIZATION', 'BALANCE ADJUSTMENT', 'CARD LOAD', 'CARD UNLOAD',
           'CHARGE BACK ADVICE', 'FEE']

How should I ensure I don't get this ValueError keeping both these columns ?

Comment: Yes, you are trying to convert the string `FEE` to a floating point number.

Comment: Skip the first column...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How does skipping help ? And why is it showing conversion error only for `FEE` and not other column values like `AUTHORIZATION` etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to convert your column into numeric types?
Also to clarify, is FEE the first value your code has to parse in the column?

Comment: I have some columns as category type and others as integer. I am trying to train my dataset using randomforest but every time I get this ValueError for some column with a column value in the stack trace.

Comment: So you want to convert all of them to dummy variables, correct?

Comment: No FEE isn't the first of the column value. Authorization is the first. I guess I have long spaces before FEE in the dataset but I wonder why it shows as 'FEE' instead of '      FEE' in when I do `df.ROWTYPE.unique()`.

Comment: Infact, I have lots of column with this similar issue. How can I ensure that each value in each column is free of spaces ? I think that should solve it.

Comment: To address this issue, slice out all string type columns and do this: `df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''))`

Comment: as in `df['ROWTYPE'].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())` for the column ROWTYPE and similarly for other such columns ?

Comment: group all the names of string type columns into an array, let's call it `str_columns`. Then you can do `df[str_columns]` to get all string values in your dataframe, the `applymap()` method will modify (in this case, remove spaces in) every single element inside the the dataframe slice `df[str_columns]`. My point is that you don't have to use this code for every single column. Just group them up, and modify everything wholesale.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148568/discussion-between-aya-and-captainmeow).